# Logistic regression using GLM for target variable which ranges between 0 and 1

Tags: r

I am going to perform logistic regression to predict a variable (GD) containing mainly 0 and 1 indicating that 0 are bad customers and 1 is good but this variable also includes values like (0.99,0.56,0.47,0.68 etc)

So, I am thinking I can use trails of 100 for let's say if my value is 0.68

It is going to be 0.68*100 and the variable will become binary in a sense that out of 100 records the logistic regression will take 68 records as good and others are bad.

Can anyone suggest me the code, how to do that in R using glm.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow, if your question does not attract answers, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get good tips on how to get improve it ;)

Comment: But if you multiply only certain values wouldn't this make them overrepresented?

Comment: Yes it will that’s why I am planning on multiplying even the 1’s and 0’s with 100.